# Sitecore.LayoutService.dll version mismatch between NuGet and Headless Services package

Tags: nuget, layout-service

On Sitecore 10.1.1, I've got `Sitecore Headless Services Server XP 18.0.0 rev. 00473` installed. According to [documentation](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering/18x/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering_1800.aspx), that's the correct version. The package brings `Sitecore.LayoutService.dll` with version 7.1.0:

[image]

Now I'd like to extend the LayoutService API. I referenced the latest available [Sitecore.LayoutService](https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore.LayoutService) NuGet pachage which has version 10.1.0. But now, when I try to reach the data via API, I receive error:

```
2396 11:41:16 ERROR Exception during Layout Service RenderItem (configuration: jss, item: {A843B9EF-04E4-4631-A2F0-EE4C6F2277E7})
cm_1         | Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
cm_1         | Message: Could not find type 'Sitecore.LayoutService.Serialization.Pipelines.GetFieldSerializer.GetIntegerFieldSerializer, Sitecore.LayoutService'
```

I checked the assembly delivered via NuGet and the type is indeed missing there. The LayoutService assembly version is 7.0.0, not 7.1.0:

[image]

Am I missing smth? How do I reference the proper 7.1 version via NuGet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree NuGet Packages for Layout Services are confusing here. But You need to use `sc-packages - Sitecore.LayoutService 7.1.0` here.

```
PM> Install-Package Sitecore.LayoutService -Version 7.1.0 -Source https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json
```

This is the correct version for you. You will find below details for dll -

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mahendra Shekhawat! Would be great to see Sitecore unlisting the packages if possible (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/policies/deleting-packages#unlisting-a-package)